# Mysql query produces different result when used as subquery

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I have defined tables PARTS, CATALOG, and PLIST using following code in Mysql:

```
create table parts (
  PID int
);
create table catalog(
  SID varchar(3),
  PID int
);
create table plist(
  PID int
);
insert into parts values (1),(2),(3), (4);
insert into catalog values
  ("A", 1), ("A", 2), ("A", 4),
  ("B", 2), ("B", 3), ("B", 4),
  ("C", 1), ("C", 4),
  ("D", 2), ("D", 3);
insert into plist values (2), (4);
```

I want to perform the relational division operator catalog  plist. The relational division operator is not available in SQL. The following implementation works successfully in Oracle:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SID) FROM CATALOG A WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT PID FROM PLIST MINUS SELECT PID FROM CATALOG WHERE SID = A.SID);
```

Now, in MYsql MINUS operator is not available. The following query successfully implements the MINUS operation used above (with a modification introduced to independently test the query) in Mysql.

```
SELECT B.PID FROM PLIST LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT PID FROM CATALOG  WHERE SID = "C") B ON B.PID=PLIST.PID 
  WHERE B.PID IS NULL;
```

However, when I use above code as subquery to implement the relation division operator as

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SID) FROM CATALOG WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT B.PID FROM PLIST LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT A.PID FROM CATALOG A WHERE A.SID = SID) B ON B.PID = PLIST.PID
      WHERE B.PID IS NULL
);
```

I do not get the expected result. The expected result contains SID values "A" and "B" only. However, the result produced by above code contains all four SID values. This is strange because when tested independently, the subquery produces correct results (empty in case of SID equal to "A" or "B" and nonempty for other two values of SID).

I will be thankful if this strange behavior is explained by someone in this forum.

Many thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I have used alias A for the CATALOG table in inner query, instead of using it for the outer query because Mysql didn't recognize the alias used for the outer query.

Comment: I am also aware of an alternative implementation of MINUS using IN operation that I could successfully use for implementing relational division in Mysql.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is explained as follows:

The query written by me is erroneous since in the inner query, there is no difference between A.SID and SID. Hence the condition always results in TRUE.

Thus what is intended as a correlated subquery is not really so.

THIS EXPLAINS why the query result contains all four SIDs.

However, as stated in my first comment, when I used an alias for the table in outer query, and used that alias in the inner query as shown below

```
SELECT DISTINCT(SID) FROM CATALOG A WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  ( SELECT B.PID FROM PLIST LEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT PID FROM CATALOG WHERE SID = A.SID) B ON B.PID = PLIST.PID
      WHERE B.PID IS NULL
);
```

I get the error: unknown column "A.SID" in where clause.

I do not understand why the alias A is not in the scope of the subquery.